# Is it possible to create a model and child models using Rails + MongoDB/Mongoid with just JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, mongodb, mongoid

For example, I would like to create a new 'Tweet' object from the following JSON

```
{:for_user=>14248719, :message=>{:place=>nil, :user=>{:contributors_enabled=>false, :statuses_count=>217, :profile_use_background_image=>true, :friends_count=>3, :profile_background_color=>"C0DEED", :url=>nil, :following=>nil, :verified=>false, :profile_background_image_url=>"http://a3.twimg.com/a/1298748610/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", :time_zone=>nil, :favourites_count=>0, :profile_text_color=>"333333", :follow_request_sent=>nil, :profile_sidebar_fill_color=>"DDEEF6", :description=>"Lets get panda dev team rawk!", :id_str=>"95923128", :profile_background_tile=>false, :followers_count=>2, :created_at=>"Thu Dec 10 15:29:56 +0000 2009", :protected=>true, :profile_image_url=>"http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1121266473/panda01_normal.jpg", :is_translator=>false, :show_all_inline_media=>false, :geo_enabled=>false, :profile_link_color=>"0084B4", :location=>"Brighton", :name=>"letsgetpandadev", :listed_count=>0, :notifications=>nil, :profile_sidebar_border_color=>"C0DEED", :screen_name=>"letsgetpandadev", :id=>95923128, :lang=>"en", :utc_offset=>nil}, :favorited=>false, :coordinates=>nil, :text=>"another magic tweet", :in_reply_to_screen_name=>nil, :in_reply_to_user_id=>nil, :in_reply_to_status_id=>nil, :in_reply_to_status_id_str=>nil, :source=>"web", :contributors=>nil, :retweeted=>false, :in_reply_to_user_id_str=>nil, :id_str=>"44709765150015488", :retweet_count=>0, :created_at=>"Mon Mar 07 10:43:33 +0000 2011", :geo=>nil, :id=>44709765150015488, :entities=>{:urls=>[], :user_mentions=>[], :hashtags=>[]}, :truncated=>false}}
```

..and have 'message', 'message.user' etc saved as embedded child models.
Parsing the JSON and inserting that just yields a 'Tweet' object with a hash saved in the message property.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? If so, how? and if not, would it be possible through another method?

I am using Rails 3 and the Mongoid gem for MongoDB.

Thanks

Comment: this looks like a ruby hash and not like JSON. Maybe convert it with `.to_json`

Comment: Sorry, yes. I pasted the wrong thing. This was after it had been parsed from JSON into a ruby hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can -- just not with the mongoid/mongomapper wrappers. Connect via the ruby driver itself... This tutorial has more: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
test_collection = db.collection("testCollection")

doc = {"name" => "MongoDB", "type" => "database", "count" => 1,
       "info" => {"x" => 203, "y" => 102}
      }
test_collection.insert(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the message to be its own object, then you would either need to embed or reference another model that defines it.

```
class Tweet
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :message
end

class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :tweet

  field :place
  ...
end
```

When you build the attributes, you will want to construct them the same way you would a form post with nested attributes and set up your model to accept them that way.

Comment: Ok, thanks Paul. Just to confirm, it is not possible just to chuck in a blob of JSON, I will have to construct the object manually or at least manipulate the JSON in order to create the objects... even if I have 'allow_dynamic_fields: true' set in my config?

Comment: After setting up this association, everything seems to be working. I think I was hoping that it could all be dynamic and I would not have to set up these associations.